# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in AppCompatActivity onCreate

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I am seeing a bunch of ConcurrentModificationException in crash logs. Does anyone run into this before?

```
Caused by java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
       at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:787)
       at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:819)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState(FragmentManager.java:2472)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState(FragmentController.java:196)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:287)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
```

Answer (score 2):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152337205):

> [b/145832397](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145832397) makes this error impossible. That fix went out in Fragment `1.3.0-alpha01` as per [the release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha01).

Therefore you should upgrade to Fragment 1.3.0 (currently still in alpha).  If you cannot do that, the bug also mentions:

> This code path only runs when you've added a retained fragment after the state is saved (i.e., with `commitAllowingStateLoss()` or `commitNowAllowingStateLoss()`). You should avoid doing that.